# Login con datos de una API

Tags: php, javascript, json, webservice, api

Quisiera que me ayuden con un login que quiero realizar pero es capturando datos de un API, por ahora ya consulto los datos de la API y los muestro en un tabla.

```
function obtenerDatos(){
var dni = document.getElementById("dni").value;
let url = `http://10.6.0.140:3000/marcaciones/${dni}`;

const api = new XMLHttpRequest();
api.open('GET', url, true);
api.send();

api.onreadystatechange = function (){
    if (this.status == 200 && this.readyState == 4){

        let datos = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        console.log(datos.serie);
        let resultado = document.querySelector('#resultado');
        resultado.innerHTML ='';

        for(let item of datos){
            console.log(item.id, item.dni , item.marcacion);
            resultado.innerHTML +=
            `<tr>
            <th scope="row">${item.id}</th>
            <td>${item.dni}</td> 
            <td>${(item.marcacion)}</td> `
        }
    }
}}
```

Con ese codigo capturo los datos de la API y muestro en tabla, pero ahora quisiera que me permita logear con un solo dato "dni".

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esa es la data que muestra la API, para el login solo quiero usar "dni".
Algunas sugerencias de como realizar, soy nuevo en esto de las API.

Comment: Saludos Daniel, lamentablemente este tipo de preguntas se basa en opiniones y por ende, terminan siendo cerradas. Si recién estás iniciando en el tema de las web APIs, te recomiendo revisar sobre arquitectura REST https://www.tutorialspoint.com/restful/index.htm para que tengas una idea más amplia

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si tienes chance de usar **jQuery**, puedes usar la función `each`

```
$.each(datos, function( index, value ) {
  console.log( index + ": " + value.dni );
});
```

Si lo que quieres es trabajar directamente sobre el arreglo, puedes hacerlo con la llave de cada arreglo

```
console.log(datos[2].dni);
// retornará 74326862
```

[API JQuery](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)